# Orchard NHibernate Error: ExecuteReader requires an open and available connection

Tags: nhibernate, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.7

I am getting an NHibernate error in Orchard 1.7 after my blog gets hit with a certain amount of traffic volume:

```
ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed
```

Once I start getting this error, I cannot load my blog any more without restarting the site in IIS. Restarting fixes it, but the same thing happens when I get spikes of traffic in a day (<200 visits).

(I can consistently reproduce the problem by hitting my site with IIS SEO toolkit which attempts to crawl all of the pages in my site.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's fixed in 1.8. Upgrade...

Comment: Thanks. I was also able to fix it in 1.7 by enabling MARS and pulling in the changeset that fixes the session disposal per details on this thread https://orchard.codeplex.com/workitem/20544